# Show that $|ax^2+bx+c|<1$ gives us $|c|<1$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $-1<x<1$

Show that if $|ax^2+bx+c|=<1$

So :

1) $|c|=<1$

2) $|a+c|=<1$

3) $a^2+b^2+c^2=<5$

For the first one ; if I choose x=0

So |c|=<1

And choosing $x=1$ and $x=-1$ give us |a+b|=<1

So did I prove it for all $x \in [-1,1]$ ?

If No then how can I show it ?

Can someone give me a hint for the third one ?

Comment: You can't choose $x=\pm1$, you are given the range $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Note that if $a=c={1 \over 2}, b=0$, then $|ax^2+bx+c| <1 $ for all $|x|<1$ but $a+c=1$, hence 2) cannot be true.

Comment: No, showing it for three points is not proving it for the entire interval.

Comment: Check your question - does the inequality hold for all $x \in [-1, 1]$?

Comment: @copper.hat see please the edit !!! :)

Comment: Best I can do is $a^2+b^2+c^2 \le 6$.